# searchcontroller, roundedcorners not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uisearchbar, uicontainerview

[image]

[image]

[image]

This view's order is like this

```
 -View Controller

      -Fake shadow view

           -Container view

               -Search Bar
```

In normal state, roundedcorner works correctly, but when I click on it, there is some shadow. When I type something on it just the view becomes rectengular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this IBDesignable class and give rounded corner from story board

```
import Foundation
@IBDesignable class customView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.gray {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor = UIColor.gray {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var masksToBounds: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            layer.masksToBounds = masksToBounds
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 12, height: 12) {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: apply this class to your containerview view and from storyboard assign the properties to the view